# How To store faces with their normals inside .ply file or any other

Tags: opengl, 3d

I have triangular faces with there normals , But how to format them in order to view them, inside meshlab or cloudcompare.

** I am not asking how to store normals with their vertices **

Comment: The lowest common denominator of mesh formats is [the Wavefront .obj format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). Export your mesh to that and import in the tools you mentioned.

Comment: What i am asking is :-  look at below file i am saving vertex with their normals and faces with their normals. Now in which format may i open this in ??

https://anotepad.com/notes/kedgkd

Comment: Well, it looks like a .ply file. Did opening it in meshlab or cloudcompare give a useful error?

Comment: Actually i search it on google , but no where i found that a .ply file contains normals with there faces

Comment: Normals are commonly derived from faces using the vector product of two edges of the face in a certain direction. Storing them would needlessly duplicate information.

Comment: It seems that you might not understand the question , i am asking that , i already have normals for faces . And it looks like this.. https://ibb.co/2MLLcJg

Comment: Well, the file format allows you add arbitrary properties, so I guess the answer to your question is `property float nx\nproperty float ny\nproperty float nz` after the property definition of the index list. But you still need to convince the importing programs to respect your new normals. I've found numerous references that say custom normals for faces are ignored...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189111/discussion-between-sha111-and-botje).